# Is it possible to chain accessors or sth similar in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have something like this in javascript:

```
MyObject.prototype.route = function(route) {
  this.route = route;
  return this;
};
```

The required usage would be:

```
myInstance.route('hello').otherFunctionOfMyObject();
```

and afterwards as

```
var text = myInstance.route;
```

How would I go about writing something similar in typescript who is more strict about this.route being either a function or a property?

I tried using a typescript accessor to no avail.

Comment: This wouldn't work in most typed languages (changing a member from a function to a property) unless it's completely dynamic. In your example, it's a `function` that is overwritten with a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` and just port over you JavaScript to TypeScript.

If you *must* use classes then you can't do that because a member of a class can only be either a function or a getter not both

Comment: Yeah I thought so, but I was hoping that typescript would have a way to use a nested ES5 accessor with configurable property toggling to accomplish something like that.

Answer (score 1):

FYI your javascript is wrong. As soon as you call this function

```
MyObject.prototype.route = function(route) { // RouteA function
  this.route = route; // RouteB
  return this;
};
```

Then you can no longer access the `RouteA` function using `instance.route` because `instance.route` points to the `RouteB` passed into `RouteA` and JavaScript does not look at `instance.__proto__.route` (which is `RouteA`).

Comment: I do not get what you mean exactly. Can you show a usage example where this would not work? Do you mean if I call something like instance.route('first').route('second') that the 'first' would be overwritten?